# Rxjs nested subscribe with multiple inner subscriptions

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, rxjs

Original promise based code I'm trying to rewrite:

```
parentPromise
    .then((parentResult) => {
        childPromise1
            .then(child1Result => child1Handler(parentResult, child1Result));
        childPromise2
            .then(child1Result => child2Handler(parentResult, child2Result));
        childPromise3
            .then(child1Result => child3Handler(parentResult, child3Result));
    });
```

I'm trying to figure a way how to avoid the [nested subscriptions anti-pattern](https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-use-flattening-operators-instead-of-nested-subscriptions) in the following scenario:

```
parent$
    .pipe(takeUntil(onDestroy$))
    .subscribe((parentResult) => {
        child1$
            .pipe(takeUntil(onDestroy$))
            .subscribe(child1Result => child1Handler(parentResult, child1Result));
        child2$
            .pipe(takeUntil(onDestroy$))
            .subscribe(child2Result => child2Handler(parentResult, child2Result));
        child3$
            .pipe(takeUntil(onDestroy$))
            .subscribe(child3Result => child3Handler(parentResult, child3Result));
    });
```

What would be the correct 'RxJS way' to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems pretty strange to me. You're creating new subscription for each child every time `parentResult` arrives. Even though those eventually indeed will be destroyed (assuming `onDestroy$` implementation is correct), seems wrong.

You probably want `withLatestFrom(parent$)` and three separate pipes for each child.

It might look something like: 
`child1$.pipe(takeUntil(globalDeath$), withLatestFrom(parent$)).subscribe(([childResult, parentResult]) => ...)`. Not sure if my JS is correct, can't test it at the moment; but the point is: you're getting the latest result from the `parent$` every time `child1$` fires. Note that you can reverse the direction if necessary (`withLatestFrom(child1$)`).

Comment: This will cause multiple subscriptions to the parent, so make sure this is acceptable or multicast it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can: 1) pass `parent$` through `share`, and 2) use `flatMap` three times, something like:

```
const sharedParent$ = parent$.pipe(share());

sharedParent$.pipe(
    flatMap(parentResult => forkJoin(of(parentResult), child1$)), 
    takeUntil(onDestroy$)),
.subscribe((results) => child1Handler(...results)); // repeat for all children
```

(If there's more than 2 children, extracting that into a function with child stream and handler as parameters is a good idea).

That's following the original behavior of waiting with subscribing children until `parent$` emits. If you don't need that, you can skip `flatMap` and just `forkJoin` `sharedParent$` and children.

Answer (score 0):

How about using higher order observables?  Something like this:

```
const parentReplay$ = parent$.pipe(shareReplay(1));

of(
  [child1$, child1Handler],
  [child2$, child2Handler],
  [child3$, child3Handler]
).pipe(
  mergeMap([child$, handler] => parentReplay$.pipe(
    mergeMap(parentResult => child$.pipe(
      tap(childResult => handler(parentResult, childResult))
    )
  )
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Promises then the corresponding Observables emit only once and then complete.

If this is the case, you can use `forkJoin` to execute in parallel the child Observables.

So the code could look like

```
parent$.pipe(
   takeUntil(onDestroy$),
   // wait for parent$ to emit and then move on
   // the following forkJoin executes the child observables in parallel and emit when all children complete - the value emitted is an array with the 3 notifications coming from the child observables
   concatMap(parentResult => forkJoin(child1$, child2$, child3$)).pipe(
      // map returns both the parent and the children notificiations
      map(childrenResults => ({parentResult, childrenResults})
   )
).subscribe(
  ({parentResult, childrenResults}) => {
      child1Handler(parentResult, childrenResults[0]);
      child1Handler(parentResult, childrenResults[1]);
      child1Handler(parentResult, childrenResults[2]);
  }
)
```